# How to call method on object via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following code where I want to wrap a lot of similar objects. They are not the same and I don't know beforehand.

It all works great - except now I sometimes need to call a method .Close(); and check it's state.

How do I do this?

```
public static TResult TryGetData<TResult>(Func<TResult> f)
{
    if (???.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
    {
        ???.Close();                
    }

    try
    {
        return f();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return default(TResult);
    }
}
```

Bonus info:
Can't change the way the objects are created.

All objects inherits from this:
System.ServiceModel.ClientBase in a generic way too.

HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEELP :-)

Comment: you want call method from what? anyway you can use [GetField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53seyfee(v=vs.110).aspx) or [GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: is `f` the same as `???`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

Call method:

```
objectInstance.GetType().GetMethod("Close").Invoke(objectInstance,null);
```

Access property:

```
objectInstance.GetType().GetProperty("State").GetValue(objectInstance);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need reflection here, you mention that you inherit from [`ClientBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141(v=vs.110).aspx), which according to documentation is where `State` and `Close()` reside

Therefore you just need restrictions

```
public static TResult TryGetData<TResult>(Func<TResult> f) where TResult : ClientBase
```

This assumes that `???` is the same as `TResult`